# Hibernate index using hyperjaxb3

Tags: hibernate, xsd, hyperjaxb

I am trying to add an index to a simple attribute using hyperjaxb, using the following fragment in my .xjb file:

```
<jxb:bindings node="./xsd:attribute[@name='serviceCode']">
    <annox:annotate target="getter">
        <annox:annotate annox:class="org.hibernate.annotations.Index" name="product_index_serviceCode" columnNames="SERVICE_CODE"/>
    </annox:annotate>
    <hj:basic>
        <orm:column length="120"/>
    </hj:basic>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I am getting an "Error parsing annotation.' error on the line where I have the annotation in the .xjb file. If I remove the annotation, then it works fine, but obviously, I do not get the index. I also tried moving the annotation inside the hj:basic element. In that case I do not get an error, but there is again no index being generated.

Comment: Did you add Hibernate annotations JAR as a plugin next to the JAXB Annotate plugin? The annotate plugin needs annotation classes to parse XML. Alternatively you can just define you annotation in Java syntax (with fully qualified classes).

Comment: @lexicore Thanks, I figured that out sometime back, but forgot to update the StackOverflow entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lexicore indicated, you need to put Hibernate annotations JAR as a plugin next to the JAXB Annotate plugin.